# Question about the conditions for the alternating series test

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I was recently reading Paul's online notes on the Alternating Series Test. I noticed that he says "for this proof to work we really do need [the absolute value of the terms] to be positive and decreasing for all n" . I was wondering why this test doesn't apply when the terms are positive and decreasing 'eventually' as is the case in the comparison and integral tests.

Comment: Sounds like you are wondering for a good reason. Please show your way of doing it in detail. As it is the question is on the brink of being closed.

Comment: You're correct that "eventually" decreasing (with limit $0$) is enough.